# Найти подстроку и удалить её из файлов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash

Я попал в ситуацию более чем прозаичную: обновил этой ночью php до 5.4.x, почитав о его вкусностях, но не тут то было. добрая доля сайтов, (а их у меня не один и не два, и даже не десять) перестали открываться, вылетая с публичной фатальной ошибкой что нельзя выполнить `session_register();` - о том, что из релиза её убрали, я узнал только когда заметил, что "The website is DOWN !" и погуглил, что же это за функция такая.

Идея вот в чём: написать скрипт, который рекурсивно пробежится по `*.php`, и если увидит там сию функцию, мочил бы её в месте с параметрами, ну или хотя бы комментировал строку, где оно встречается, но увы сейчас я в состоянии полуистерическом, и не способен сам прийти к решению вопроса. Просьба к онлайновым светлым головам помочь моему несчастью.

Comment: Что-нибудь типа

      find ./ -name '*.php' -exec grep -q session_register {} \; -print | xargs sed -i -e 's,session_register[^;]\+;,,'

(Только сначала -- backup)

Comment: Погладил кота, устаканил нервы, погуглил задачу.
Пришёл к:

find -type f -name \*.php -exec sed -i -r 's/session_register/#session_register/g' {} \;

Скрипт отработал, сйты поднялись, котэ в ногах, можно поспать.

бекапы у меня автоматические, хранится всё за три дня, благо поднял эту фичу после очередного падения с потерей большого количества ценных данных. Как вы вставили код с подсветкой без визуального редактора?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. (Пустая строка впереди и четыре или больше пробела отступа -- это то?).

Answer (score 2):

Используйте

```
find -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's/session_register/#&/g' {} \;
```

Эта комманда найдет все PHP-файлы и заменит `session_register` на `#session_register`. Шаблон замены содержит `&`, обратную ссылку на целое совпадение, т.е. `session_register`. `-i` файлы будут обновлены автоматически (если нужно, сделайте резервное копирование заблаговременно).